# Hiding divs with javascript collapse all

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making divs with holds content and my problem is how to get all divs to collapse.
 Problem here is that the code needs to be dynamic since we don't know how many divs going to be made.

First here is my javascript:

```
function pageLoad() 

var j = 1; while(j>0)

collapseAll($('div'+j,'divx',+j));
j++;
```

This part handles collapse when page is loaded. All divs need to be collapsed.
in code it should be like this:

```
<a onclick="div('div1');" > //this at first time
 <div id="div1">
 content
</div>    
<a onclick="divx('divx1'); 
<div id="divx1">
 content
</div>
<!-- this at next when div is created -->
<a onclick="div('div2');" > 
<div id="div2">
 content
</div>
<a onclick="divx('divx2'); ">
<div id="divx2">
 content
</div>
```

and so on.. Problem here is that when code creates new div  it gives same name for div that is used in earlier part.

forexample:

```
<a onclick="divx('divx2'); ">
<div id="divx2">
 content
 </div>

//new div created:
<a onclick="divx('divx2'); ">
<div id="divx2">
 content
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with something like the following. Please note that it requires jQuery (http://jquery.com).

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('a.collapse').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.collapsible').find('.collapse-container').toggle();
    });

    $('a#collapse-all').click(function() {
        $('.collapse-container').hide();
    });

    // Added: Collapse all on load.
    $('.collapse-container').hide();
});
</script>

<div class="collapsible">
    <a class="collapse" href="#">Click to expand / collapse</a>
    <div class="collapse-container">
        content
    </div>
</div>

<div class="collapsible">
    <a class="collapse" href="#">Click to expand / collapse</a>
    <div class="collapse-container">
        content
    </div>
</div>

<a id="collapse-all" href="#">Click to collapse all</a>
```

Comment: I don't think you need extra markup to that, but your structure of course is better than what the OP used

Comment: @Nicola this seems (to me at least) a much clearer and more concise solution and could even perform better on large content. This is what classes are for and it avoids interacting with nested DIV's.

Comment: i agree with you (as i said in the comment your markup is much better), it's just that sometimes you don't have control over the markup! in any case +1, the answer is very clear

Comment: Thanks for answer. Any idea how to change collapse all link to collapse all divs when page is loaded?

Comment: @jimbo84 I have added this to the example

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Attribute Starts With Selector and save yourself a lot of typing by targetting all divs whose id starts with div:

```
$('a').click(function(){
   //do something to all the divs, hide them for example
   $('div[id^="div"']).hide();
   //hide only the next div:
   $(this).next('div[id^="div"']).hide()
   //hide all the divs until the nezt <a>
   $(this).nextUntil('a').hide();

});
```